# how to get the function name and arg from a function pointer in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I get the inner function's name from the outer arrow function expression, `'foo'` as for the provided example code and the inner function's `'arg1'` name too, without invoking the outer function?

```js
var func = data => foo(arg1, data)

console.log(func)
```

Comment: `func.toString()` will get the function source code in string format. You can extract it from there

Comment: Thing is, that arrow function there doesn't have a name. It's an unnamed function that has been assigned to a variable. You could do `var bar = func;`, and `func === bar`, and neither `func` nor `bar` is the 'name'. Otherwise you should be able to extract arguments using `toString().split( '=>' ).shift()` and taking it from there.

Comment: I'm also confused by "Function pointer". Javascript has no concept of function pointers. Are you assuming that an arrow function calling another function is a "function pointer"? Because it is not, as your arrow function can also contain a code block. It's just a one-liner code block in this case, so there's no good way to extract, say, `foo` from it, as its heavily dependent on the way the function is written...

Comment: What if the function would be `data => bar && foo(arg1, data)`, or even more complicated expressions and statements. While it's technically _possible_ to extract the name in this case (from `toString()`…), it's really questionable why you'd want this, as it's trivial to manufacture alternative situations where any solution will break. So… why do you want this in the first place?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254476/discussion-on-question-by-jac-how-to-get-the-function-name-and-arg-from-a-functi); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: @Jac ... While it would be easy to extract function and parameter name from the provided example code ... e.g like `const { funcName, paramName } = (/=>\s*(?<funcName>[\w]+)\((?<paramName>[\w]+)/).exec(String(func))?.groups ?? {};` ... what or how does it help your actual use case? The parameter name does not matter at all since one only needs to know a parameter's position in a function's `arguments` array. And utilizing the function name does make sense only in case one knows in which context the function has to be invoked (e.g. `window[fctName]()`). What's your real use case/scenario?

Comment: @Jac ... Your thread somehow got revived by some new comments. There were also some questions ask by the audience which you might answer.